How do I find online chess instructors?
How do I find a chess teaches who is teaching online? Is there a "online marketplace" where to find teacher? Ideally a Master+ level.
I feel stuck and I'd like to try to take some chess classes to identify my holes and do some specific chess training.

You can find a chess coach on various online sites:

Chess.com: https://www.chess.com/coaches
Lichess.org: https://lichess.org/coach
FIDE (Arena): https://coaches.chessarena.com/en/
Individual Federations: USCF example, http://www.uschess.org/index.php/Scholastic-Misc/Certified-Chess-Coach-List.html

Many of those listed have titles (e.g., NM, FM, IM, GM).
Lichess.org allows you to sort by language, country, and/or rating. Chess.com allows you to search the coaches list by country and/or rating.
There are also a variety of websites promoting various models of online-focused training and/or coaching.  One notable example, among many others, is Killer Chess Training (https://killerchesstraining.com/).
